# User Interface buttons on an image view

Tags: java, android, button, android-studio, imageview

[cell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxeYR.png)

Im using this picture above for my app I am making on android studio. As you can see, the image has different cells; I want to the user of the app to be able to tap each cell and the colour will change.

I have tried putting buttons on top of each cell but the buttons do not overlap directly on top of the selected cell.

Please if anyone has suggestions on how I can create a user interface with each cell of the image, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Is this dynamic table? Or it is just image as background?

Comment: it is an image background @Mike